# How can I get this listener to work from a ChildViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I made an app where a Mapbox map is loaded in a view and tracks the user's location with the following code:

```
func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MGLUserLocation?) {
    print(userLocation)
}
```

This code works fine on it's own as a ViewController, but when I add the view to a scrollview with `addChildViewController`, the code doesn't run. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the whole piece of code you use to add the view to a scrollview?

Comment: I figured it out. There was a delegate missing in the code. Thanks tho!